# Invalid value for key attachdbfilename C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p5.html) to create my first SQL Server database which is linked with my C# Windows form application. However when I compile my application in VS 2012 I get the following error:

> "Invalid value for key attachdbfilename".

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\Calculations.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I have searched many sites to resolve my problem but it's still persisting and I'm running out of ideas.

PS: In the connection string `Calculations.mdf` is my database name.

Comment: I get this error: http://i.epvpimg.com/HcKch.png

Answer (score 0):

At AttachDbFilename should be the path to your mdf file.

Comment: But it is the path to my mdf file: AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\Calculations.mdf

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(LocalDB)\v11.0` by `.`, so it should be like this :

```
Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\Calculations.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: I see also the initial catalog is missing from connection string try this please :  `Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Calculations;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\Calculations.mdf;Integrated Security=True`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I got this error this time: http://i.epvpimg.com/TJ00h.png I think it has something to do with permissions but I ran VS as Admin and the same error still persisted. I also checked the permission on the file and I already have all permissions..

Answer (score 0):

For your `AttachDbFilename` value, instead of using `|DataDirectory|\bin\Debug\Calculations.mdf`, try to give a full path like "C:\Project\Calculations.mdf". Because you can't verify that your path is correct with your current method.

Comment: That error basically means the program cannot locate your database or your database server is not up. Check your data source to ensure it's correct. If it's correct, try setting database name for the value "Initial Catalog" like Ayman suggested

Answer (score 0):

Delete `|DataDirectory|` and specify the full path to the file. For instance:

```
AttachDbFilename=C:Project\Calculations.mdf
```

It should work now!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `AttachDbFilename=./your-file-name.mdf;`